# Como subdividir parte HTML

Tags: html

Como posso colocar uma parte do HTML em arquivo separado, e reutilizar o código.

Tenho um MENU que será utilizado em várias páginas do projeto. Mas no caso de fazer a manutenção de código, seria mais fácil se criasse uma página: MENU.html.

E nas próximas páginas, eu chamasse o o menu que deveria estar dentro de uma  *DIV*

Comment: Você está utilizando alguma linguagem *server-side*?

Comment: Não. Somente HTML e CSS.

Comment: Você consegue fazer algo com JavaScript, no máximo. Tem o assunto discutido no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8988855/1452488).

Comment: No projeto ficou vetado o uso do JavaScript. Também não posso utilizar PHP.

Comment: Então você não possui opções. No máximo utilizar um pre-processador de HTML, tal como o Pug, que te permite esse tipo de importação.

Comment: Com HTML puro, use um iframe.

Comment: Seria bom você editar sua pergunta e colocar que não está usando nenhuma linguagem _server-side_ e também não pode ser uma solução com _JavaScript_. Isso pode melhorar a qualidade de suas respostas.

Answer (score 2):

Como dito nos comentários você pode utilizar a tag `iframe`.

iframe.html

```
<iframe src="menu_frame.html" style="border:none;"></iframe>
```

menu_frame.html

```
<a href="#">Menu</a>
```

Podes usar também a tag `object`. Verificar compatibilidade dos navegadores.

object.html

```
<object data="menu_frame.html"></object>
```

Answer (score -1):

Desenvolver um app que tenha os menus em arquivos de menus separados dos conteúdos, voce resolve o problema da manutenção, mas cria outro problema, a renderização.

Como voce não deu detalhes do seu projeto, vou assumir que esta usando um framework css e php, basicamente voce pode dividir suas paginas em tres partes

- Menus (header)
- Conteudo (body)
- rodapé (footer)

Arquivo menu.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
```

Arquivo content.html

```
<h1>Seu conteudo Aqui!</h1>
```

Arquivo footer.html

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

No seu arquivo index.php

```
<?php
require "menu.html";

$url = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); // Obtem a url e passa em forma de array
switch($url[1]) { // compara o url para saber qual pagina carregar
    case "home":
        require "content.html";
    case "sobre":
        require "sobre.html";
    default:
        require "content.html";
}

require "footer.html";
?>
```

Nesse caso, em outras palavras, você vai criar seu sistema de rotas.

tenho um exemplo que ainda estou estudando, mas da uma olhada lá que voce vai entender melhor o que tentei explicar.

https://github.com/henriquek3/economize

Comment: Não fui eu quem negativou, mas o AP quer em HTML puro...